# TypeScript: How to make object from array of tuple?

Tags: typescript

I have following array of tuple, need to make an object from, how?

```
Object.keys(invoiceItems)?.map(function (key, item) {
  [key, 1];
}
```

I know in Swift `Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:` method call I need, what about in Typescript?

Comment: Object.fromEntries

Comment: Does JavaScript actually have tuples (outside of this [TC39 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-record-tuple))?

Comment: @jarmod Not exactly, but TypeScript **does** have a type signature for tuples that differs from arrays (though in execution, they behave the same).

Comment: @jarmod you have used 'let aa = Object.keys(invoiceItems).forEach((key)....' which will return undefined, try using the same with map!!

Comment: @WasitShafi no idea what you're referring to here. Nobody used `forEach` in this post.

Comment: @János   
/jarmod
  please dare to click on edited 13 min ago :) and sorry for the wrong tag!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that by tuples you mean two-element arrays, you can use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to create such object:

```js
const entries = [
  [ "value1", 42 ],
  [ "value2", 17 ],
  [ "value3", 51 ],
];

const object = Object.fromEntries(entries);

console.log(object);
```

Comment: still a problem, would you check? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69108183/typescipt-why-object-fromentries-does-not-accept-array-of-tuple

Answer (score 0):

Here I assume your invoice items with some dummy data, below are 2 ways to create object with `key:value`

```js
const invoiceItems = [[101, 'Coffee'], [102, 'Tea'], [103, 'Book']]

// Method 1
const o =  Object.fromEntries(invoiceItems);
console.log('o :', o)


// Method 2
const o2 = {}
Object.keys(invoiceItems).forEach(i => o2[invoiceItems[i][0]] = invoiceItems[i][1])
console.log('o2 :', o2)
```