# TypeScript: Why Object.fromEntries does not accept array of tuple?

Tags: typescript

1. I make a array of tuple
2. Then convert it to object with `Object.fromEntries`
3. Then I would assign to a `<{ [formFieldId: string]: number }>` type.

What is wrong here?

```
const [itemsWithSelection, setItemsWithSelection] = useState<{ [formFieldId: string]: number }>(itemsWithSelection2)
if (!itemsWithSelection2) {
  let aa = Object.keys(invoiceItems).forEach((key) =>
    [key, 1]
  )
  setItemsWithSelection(Object.fromEntries(aa))
}
```

and got this error:

```
./components/product/InvoiceItemsToDeliver.tsx:30:44
Type error: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(entries: Iterable<readonly [PropertyKey, number]>): { [k: string]: number; }', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<readonly [PropertyKey, number]>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(entries: Iterable<readonly any[]>): any', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<readonly any[]>'.

  28 |     [key, 1]
  29 |   )
> 30 |   setItemsWithSelection(Object.fromEntries(aa))
     |                                            ^
  31 | }
```

Comment: `forEach` doesn't return anything - `aa` is always `undefined`.

Comment: I tried `{return [key, 1]}` also, same result

Comment: Because `.forEach()` doesn't return anything...

Comment: Also relevant: [Function with forEach returns undefined even with return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16392445) | [JavaScript: Difference between .forEach() and .map()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34426458) | [What does `return` keyword mean inside `forEach` function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34653612)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely want to use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) here instead of [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
const [itemsWithSelection, setItemsWithSelection] = useState<{ [formFieldId: string]: number }>(itemsWithSelection2)
if (!itemsWithSelection2) {
  let aa = Object.keys(invoiceItems).map((key) =>
    [key, 1]
  )
  setItemsWithSelection(Object.fromEntries(aa))
}
```

The first produces a new array based on the contents of the callback (or what is often called "closure" in Swift); while the second is used primarily for side effects, and always returns `undefined` (a value similar to Swift's `Void`).