# What is wrong looping with Object.entries?

Tags: javascript, html, loops

```js
{buyTicketData?.pricingOptions && (
  <select className={"select_1"}>
    {Object.entries(buyTicketData?.pricingOptions).forEach(
      ([key, value]) => {
        <option key={key}>{value.name}</option>;
      }
    )}
  </select>
)}
```

I found here how I can loop in React `return`, so, that not only the `key` is available as with `Object.keys()`, but `value` also. I can see during debugging, that call jumps in the `option` part, but in the rendered HTML no option appears, only an empty `select`. Why?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Comment: `.forEach` doesn't return anything. Also [I have mentioned this before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69108183/typescript-why-object-fromentries-does-not-accept-array-of-tuple#comment122142637_69108183)

Comment: Nor the current callback it receives.

Comment: ohhh, I learning slowly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ForEach not returning a value. You must using with map

Maybe this can help you (remove the curly bracket)

```
{buyTicketData?.pricingOptions && (
 <select className={"select_1"}>
   {Object.entries(buyTicketData?.pricingOptions).map(
    ([key, value]) => (<option key={key}>{value.name}</option>)
 )}
```

)}

Answer (score 0):

`Array.prototype.forEach` doesn't return a value.

`Array.prototype.map` [does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#using_map_to_reformat_objects_in_an_array).

Try `[1, 2, 3].forEach(x => x + 1)` in a REPL. And then try `[1, 2, 3].map(x => x + 1)`. You probably want the latter in this case.